# Redirecting queues to priority queue

Tags: python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

Hi there I'm new to Python so forgive me if I'm asking for too much. I'm using the queue module to create these. What I'm trying to do is place a string into the one queue and then redirect it to two others based on the substring.

For example my code is:

```
import queue

firstQueue = queue.Queue()
secondQueue = queue.PriorityQueue()
thirdQueue = queue.PriorityQueue()

var1 = "Hello World!"
var2 = "Hello Stack!"
var3 = "Hello Wally!"

firstQueue.put(var1)
firstQueue.put(var2)
firstQueue.put(var3)
```

At this point I want to redirect the the firstQueue to the secondQueue if the 7th character starts with 'W' in this case 'World/Wally' and anything else into the third (assuming all strings put into the first is the same length). Any help and suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use loop to go through each element in first Queue and check the condition and put it in second Queue,like this:

```
while not firstQueue.empty():
    element = firstQueue.get()
    if(element[6] == 'W'):
        secondQueue.put(element)

while not secondQueue.empty():
    print(secondQueue.get())
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I'm looking for. One more question though. Lets say that for the variable at the beginning will have 1 or 2 ("1Hello World!" and "2Hello Wally"). How do I set my priority queue so that it will print with the variable that start with 2 first?

Comment: @Jimmy That's an entirely different question, and consequently should be a separate post.  Chaining secondary questions is frowned upon here - it's not fair to keep shifting the goalposts on people who took the time to answer your original question.

Comment: @pjs Sorry about that, still fairly new to the site. I'll be sure to make a separate post about it.